# Array context assignment to empty list reference in Perl-- please explain the line " my @arr = [ ]; "

Tags: arrays, perl, list, reference, perl-data-structures

I'm new to Perl. I understand that `my @a = ();` is equivalent to `my @a;`-- both initialize an empty array. Similarly, `my $a = [];` initializes an empty array that's referenced by `$a`.

However, I'm perplexed by `my @arr = [];` which is also legal Perl. According to `ref()` and `print`, `@arr` is an array, not a reference to one. It can be pushed onto, which seems to return the number of elements in the array. But it seems to contain a reference to another array, which can also be pushed onto:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.16;

my @arr = [];
push(@arr, 1);

print join(", ", @arr) . "\n";

push(@arr[0], 11);
push(@arr[0], 12);

print "a[0]: " . join(", ", @{@arr[0]}) . "\n";
```

Outputs

```
ARRAY(0xd6ede8), 1
a[0]: 11, 12
```

What is going on here? Detail is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You must *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of every Perl program. In this case the latter would have warned you `Scalar value @arr[0] better written as $arr[0]`. In later versions of Perl it is valid to push to array *references*, and the first element of `@arr` is a reference. To access the array explicitly you would write  `@{ $arr[0] }`.

Comment: `[ ... ]` is roughly equivalent to `do { my @anon = ( ... ); \@anon }`. It returns a reference, and references are scalars, and thus legitimate values for array elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.

The `[]` always creates an array reference, and references always are scalars. Here, `my @arr = []` (or equivalently: `my @arr = ([])`) creates an array `@arr` with the first element being an array reference.

Scalars are never context-dependent! Context *only* matters for

- hash or array variables: `@foo` and `%foo`
- subroutine calls, as a call propagates the current context and can be queried via `wantarray`. Subroutines may therefore behave differently in various context.
- operators, as some operators like `,` or `..` are entirely different depending on context.

Comment: `[]` always creates an array reference except inbetween `//`, right?

Comment: @bf2020 square brackets always denote an array reference when used on an expression level. Of course, they do not have this meaning in string literals `"[0]"` or regexes `/[0]/` or when used as array subscripts `$arr[0]`.

Comment: Accepting this answer, as the information about context is useful.

Answer (score 10):

```
@arr = [];
```

is the same as

```
@arr = ([]);
```

or

```
@arr = (); $arr[0] = [];
```

It creates an array with one element, a reference to an empty array.

---

The statements

```
@arr = [];
push @arr, 1;
```

create an array with two elements: a reference to an empty array, and the scalar value `1`, like saying

```
@arr = ();
$arr[0] = [];
$arr[1] = 1;
```

---

And finally, in the statements

```
push(@arr[0], 11);
push(@arr[0], 12);
```

the first argument is equivalent to `$arr[0]`, an array reference in this example. Since Perl >=v5.14, the `push` function can operate on an array reference as well as an array, so these statements are adding elements to the (initially empty) array reference held in `$arr[0]`. So now the contents of `@arr` are equivalent what you'd get if you said

```
@arr = ();
$arr[0] = [ 11, 12 ];     # ref to array with two elements
$arr[1] = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

`[]` is a scalar value, which happens to be an array reference.

This:

```
my @arr = 42;
```

creates `@arr` as an array with a single element; that element's value is `42`. It's more clearly written as:

```
my @arr = ( 42 );
```

Very similarly, this:

```
my @arr = [];
```

also creates `@arr` as an array with a single element; that element's value is `[]`, an array reference.  It's more clearly written as:

```
my @arr = ( [] );
```

which means the same thing.

Or, if you really wanted `@arr` to be an empty array:

```
my @arr = ();
```

or possibly something like:

```
my $arr_ref = [];
```

(It is perhaps unfortunate that a scalar value in array context is treated as a single-element list; I suspect that the confusion it causes exceeds the usefulness of the feature.)